# Using java-streams for data compression

Tags: java, stream, java-stream, run-length-encoding

I have been trying to find an example of how to use java-streams as compressor. I still have not figured out how to do this and I have neither found anyone else that done it. So that I would like to do is to count occurrences, of something, in the stream as long as they are in unbroken row. A simple example would be something like this:

```
String str = "...---...";
String compressed = func(str);
compressed.equals("3.3-3.");
```

It is simple to get string into a stream of integers and count the occurrences of them. But count the occurrences in a unbroken sequence I can not figure out how to do. Is there a good way of using *.reduce* to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Stream`s are a suitable thing to use for run-length encoding. Streams and states just don't generally go well together. To keep a count of how many characters you have already counted will inevitably involve state. One way you could do it is to use `reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)` and pass anonymous classes (yes, anonymous classes) to it, and in those anonymous classes, you can keep a variable that records how many of a character there is. You can then use `StringBuilder`s to append the encoded strings.  This is not an elegant solution.

I got a little creative and did this:

```
String str = "aaaajjjfjjeeee";
String result = Pattern.compile("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)")
                    .splitAsStream(str)
                    .map(x -> 
                        Character.toString(x.charAt(0)) + 
                        Integer.toString(x.length()))
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result);
```

I am indeed using streams but I cheated a little bit and used a regex :).